# Angular 5/6 with Webpack 4

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-router

I have been trying for days now (finding error after error) to get my project to work with Webpack 4 (a necessity since I need to specify where styles, plugins, etc are implemented in my package).

My project uses a more complex router like so:

```
import { HOME_ROUTES } from './shared/routes/home.routes';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: 'Home' }, children: HOME_ROUTES},
<more routes here>
]
```

The children are then used to lazy load modules so that I can share layouts.

Otherwise, my project is rather normal (but very modular to share layouts, cards, styles, etc for performance).

Does anyone know how to configure Webpack 4 to work with this setup? (I have my project tree below if it helps)

It could be easier if someone has a working example of Webpack 4 with Angular 5 (I haven't been able to find one that works with my setup). If you would like to see my project files I can provide them.

*Project Tree:*

```
-src
  -app
      -layouts
      -pages
      --app.routes.ts
      -(app module/files)
      -shared
          -routes
          -(cards, auth, directives, navigation, more)
          -shared.module.ts
      -assets
          -css
          -img
          -js
          -sass
      -(index.html, main.ts, and standard files)
```

(I have combined and left out parts for simplicity)

Comment: Webpack and angular versions should not be an issue alone [I think](https://angular.io/guide/webpack#webpack-an-introduction). Can you provide the exact errors, codes, anything that can be useful?

Comment: @ForestG I just got it to work (I'll probably upload my configuration later), my issue was a combination of using @ngtools/webpack (wont work at all in production - reverted back to standard ts loaders), the location of my routes (angular-router-loader has specific requirements on their GitHub), and the location of my styles (I ended up importing them in the main.ts). But thanks reaching out, I was about to give up honestly.

Comment: @Drei Could you upload your configuration? I am having difficulties getting a similar setup to work. Thanks